# Selecting all rows that match parts of a string

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have a table of people

```
Id | Name | Info
1  | Bob  | some info
2  | Mark | some info
```

And I have a list of names in a `string` *separated by commas* which looks like:

`"Mark, Bob, John"`

I need an *SQL command* that would select all rows that *match the names* in the list.

Any idea how to do it?

It's in **c#** on wpf and the database is **PostgreSQL** if that matters.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM people WHERE Name in ('Mark', 'Bob', 'John')` . (First your C# would need to split the string by the commas and feed each one to the IN statement as a parameter)

Comment: So you're trying to separate the names, then look for them in a table? C# should separate the names, SQL should look through the table.

Comment: Yeah that would work. But how do I feed an unknown number of strings as parameters to an sql command?

Comment: @Martynas you don't have to include several sql parameters  as per comment of ADyson under in clause you can pass your commas separated string but remember each comma separated strings should enclose between single quotes   it should looks like SELECT * FROM people WHERE Name in ('Mark', 'Bob', 'John')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, you can try building parametrized query:

```
string names = "Mark, Bob, John";

string[] filters = names
  .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(name => name.Trim())
  .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
  .ToArray();

//TODO: Put the right class instead of SqlConnection
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere")) {
  connection.Open();

  using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.CommandText =
      $@"select *
           from MyTable
          where Name in ({string.Join(", ", filters.Select((name, i) => $"@prm_Name{i}"))})";

    //TODO: Change AddWithValue into Add and provide the RDBMS type
    for (int i = 0; i < filters.Length; ++i)
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@prm_Name{i}", filters[i]);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create an ad-hoc query from your name string like:

```
string Names = "Mark, Bob, John";

//Step 1: add quotes to Names 
var names = Names.Split(',').Select(x => $"'{x}'").ToList();

//Step 2: Join Quoted Names
var result = String.Join(",", names.ToArray());

//Step 3 Create Ad hoc query
string query = $"SELECT * FROM people WHERE NAME IN ({result})";
```

Comment: Be careful with *hardcoding*: `string Names = "D'Artagnan";` will ruin the query (let alone *sql injection*)

Comment: This almost works but the query string turns out as:
    "SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE NAME IN ('Mark',' Bob',' John')"
and because of the spaces before the name the query only returns the row with the firs name in the list and doesn't find other names.

Answer (score 1):

> I need an SQL command that would select all rows that match the names in the list.

How about [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name IN ('Mark', 'Bob', 'John')
```

Comment: This doesn't seems relevant to the question.. or at max just half of a solution

Comment: The list is a string , not a manual list . Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608630/5353753

Answer (score 0):

You should take the string apart with C# first. There are many different ways to do the loop, but after you substring the names, place them in an array or a list or something. Within the loop, look for the names using the LIKE clause.

```
'SELECT *
  FROM myTable
    WHERE LOWER(nameField) LIKE LOWER(%' + variable + '%)';
```

Not sure how you're building your SQL but if you are using a string it would look kind of like this. You can take out the LIKE if you're only looking for direct matches. Its better to place all values in either lowercase or uppercase to make sure you're getting them UNLESS you know FOR SURE you want Mark not mark or MARK etc. I do not know C#, so I am sure there's a much better way, with adding parts of an array together with commas and such to use the `IN` operator.